# JQuery same classes different selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got this problem, I know it can be solved quickly but I don't get there.

I have the following html code:

```
<section class="actualite">
                <div class="actualite-text">
<h3 class="title">Nam Libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio. </h3>
                    <div class="text-post">A</div>
                    <a class="lire btn btn-default">Lire</a>
                </div>
</section>

<section class="actualite">
                <div class="actualite2-bg"></div>
                <div class="actualite-text">    
<h3 class="title">Nam Libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio. </h3>  


                    <div class="text-post">B</div>
                    <a class="lire btn btn-default">Lire</a>
                </div>
</section>

<section class="actualite">
                <div class="actualite3-bg"></div>
                <div class="actualite-text">     
<h3 class="title">Nam Libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio. </h3>   


                    <div class="text-post">C</div>
                    <a class="lire btn btn-default">Lire</a>
                </div>
</section>
```

Actually my code has a lot of text inside class `.text-post`, but this has `overflow:hidden` and a fixed height to hide the text. What I wanted is to show the entire text when clicking the button `.lire` but I wanted it without different classes. I wanted the classes to stay with the same name. Individually I could make it easy.

This is my JQuery code:

```
$('.lire').click(function () {
        var tx = $('.text-post'),
        curHeight = tx.height(),
        autoHeight = tx.css('height', 'auto').height();
        var boxheight = autoHeight + 120;
        tx.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
        $('.actualite-text').animate({height:boxheight}, 200);

});
```

This works. When I click the button both div's (`.actualite-text` and `.text-post`) expand, but they expand in all sections because they have the same class ofc. But I wanted to do this with the same classes and that they would individually expand. I know this would be easy with `.parent()` or `.closest()` but I have tried without success.

If you didn't understand my problem, please tell me. I hope this doesn't get too confusing.

Best regards.

Comment: you mean you want to expand it one by one ?

Comment: @Prog Yes and it is done. But not working correctly, but my question is answered.

Comment: h3Height = $(this).closest('.title').height() - can anyone tell me why this doesn't get the height of the closest h3?

Comment: Solved: `h3Height = (this).parent().find('.title').height()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targetting all `text-post`, instead target related `text-post`, see below code

```
$('.lire').click(function () {
        //get previous text-post
        var tx = $(this).prev('.text-post'),
        curHeight = tx.height(),
        autoHeight = tx.css('height', 'auto').height();
        var boxheight = autoHeight + 120;
        tx.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
        //get parent actualite-text
        $(this).closest('.actualite-text').animate({height:boxheight}, 200);

});
```

Comment: This works, the problem is that the height of both divs is not consistent. I am testing with different text sizes, and in the smaller texts the div goes up and clears some text for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correct selector to target sibling `.text-post` and closest `.actualite-text`:

***For  sibling `.text-post`***

```
var tx = $(this).prev();
```

or

```
var tx = $(this).siblings('.text-post');
```

***For closest `.actualite-text`***

```
$(this).closest('.actualite-text');
```

or

```
$(this).parent();
```

**Complete Code:**

```
 $('.lire').click(function () {
    var tx = $(this).prev();
    curHeight = tx.height(),
    autoHeight = tx.css('height', 'auto').height();
    var boxheight = autoHeight + 120;
    tx.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
    $(this).closest('.actualite-text').animate({height:boxheight}, 200);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but as I posted the problem is that the height of both divs is not consistent. I am testing with different text sizes, and in the smaller texts the div goes up and clears some text for some reason. This is another problem, the answered one is already done.

Answer (score 0):

> When I click the button both div's (.actualite-text and .text-post) expand, but they expand in all sections because they have the same class ofc

The usual solution here is to work only within the section, using `closest` to go up to the second level, then `find` to find the ones to change. In this case, for instance:

```
$('.lire').click(function () {
        // Get the section by finding it relative to the clicked "button"
        var section = $(this).closest(".actualite");

        // Work within it using `find`
        var tx = section.find('.text-post'),
        curHeight = tx.height(),
        autoHeight = tx.css('height', 'auto').height();
        var boxheight = autoHeight + 120;
        tx.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
        section.find('.actualite-text').animate({height:boxheight}, 200);

});
```

Working within the section is a powerful technique because it's not very *fragile*. For instance, in your case, `.text-post` is the immediate previous sibling of the button and `.actualite-text` is its immediate parent, so in theory you could use `prev` (or `siblings`) and `parent`. But then that will break if you change the HTML at all, whereas with the above you can change the HTML *within the section* all you want, provided you keep the section wrapper and don't change the class names.